# How to create a QTimer that runs independent of the main thread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer

I’m working on a QT QML and embedded STM32 project where an oven is being controlled by a PC via serial communications.  Everything was going great until I tried to add a timed heartbeat signal to let both sides know that the other was still there and talking.  The idea was to use a QTimer on the PC side to send a heartbeat packet if the PC had not received any oven data for more than a couple of seconds. The oven would then acknowledge the heartbeat and both sides would know that the other was still connected and running.

My problem has been with getting the QTimer to work without it being created in the main.c file.  I have been working on this for several days trying any suggested solution I can find. NO Joy!  I have gotten many different error messages. Like:

QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread

QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication

I’m still pretty new using QT and I have both search the internet and purchased and watched several Udemy tutorials trying to learn more. I have not found a working example or a good explanation of how this works and/or how it should be done.

The attached code is what I currently have. Please feel free to comment on any part of it.

The goal is to have the HeartBeatTimer class use a QTimer () that is reset by the SerialCom class every time data is received from the oven.  If received data stops, a heartbeat will be sent to verify the connection, not heartbeat response the ALARM!!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated (possibly a working example).

Thanks Jim

```
#define HEARTBEATTIMER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>

class HeartBeatTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit HeartBeatTimer(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void Reset();

private:
    QThread m_workerThread;
    QTimer m_heartBeat;

signals:

public slots:
    void ThreadStarted();
    void TimedOut();

};

#endif // HEARTBEATTIMER_H
```

```
// The heart Beat timer is reset whenever the PC receives any serial
// communication from the Oven.

#include "heartBeatTimer.h"

#define HbTimeOut       2000

HeartBeatTimer::HeartBeatTimer(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    this->moveToThread(&m_workerThread);

    connect(&m_workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(ThreadStarted()));
    connect(&m_heartBeat, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(TimedOut()));

    m_workerThread.start();
}

void HeartBeatTimer::TimedOut()
{
    qDebug() << "Timer...";
}

// Starts or restarts the timer.
void HeartBeatTimer::Reset()
{
    m_heartBeat.start(HbTimeOut);
    qDebug() << "Reset...";
}

void HeartBeatTimer::ThreadStarted()
{
    m_heartBeat.start(HbTimeOut);
}
```

Comment: Why is there a need for a QThread at all?

Answer (score 0):

I  create qtimer object in `HeartBeatTimer::ThreadStarted`  use `new` operator.

Should be no error messages.

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QTimer>
#include <qpUSHbUTTON>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include<list>
#include <iterator>
#include<thread>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>

class HeartBeatTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit HeartBeatTimer(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~HeartBeatTimer();
private:
    QThread m_workerThread;
    QTimer* m_heartBeat;

signals:
    void SigReset();
public slots:
    void Reset();
    void ThreadStarted();
    void TimedOut();
};

#define HbTimeOut       2000

HeartBeatTimer::HeartBeatTimer(QObject* parent)
    : QObject{ parent }
{
    moveToThread(&m_workerThread);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(SigReset()), this, SLOT(Reset()));
    connect(&m_workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(ThreadStarted()));
    m_workerThread.start();
}

HeartBeatTimer::~HeartBeatTimer()
{
    m_workerThread.quit();
    m_workerThread.wait();
}

void HeartBeatTimer::TimedOut()
{
    qDebug() << "Timer...";
}

// Starts or restarts the timer.
void HeartBeatTimer::Reset()
{
    m_heartBeat->start(HbTimeOut);
    qDebug() << "Reset...";
}

void HeartBeatTimer::ThreadStarted()
{
    m_heartBeat = new QTimer();
    connect(m_heartBeat, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(TimedOut()));
    m_heartBeat->start(HbTimeOut);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QPushButton pb;
    HeartBeatTimer hbt;
    QObject::connect(&pb, &QPushButton::clicked, &hbt,&HeartBeatTimer::SigReset );
    pb.show();
    return app.exec();
}
#include"main.moc"
```

Comment: The code you provides doesn't seem to be correct. According to the documentation for Qt timers: `"In multithreaded applications, you can use the timer mechanism in any thread that has an event loop"`, but I don't see you start any event loop in your thread. This means the `timeout` signal will not be emitted. Please double check this.

Comment: Thank You kenash0625

Your code works as designed but, when I move the creation of the hbt object from the main.c file to my serial communications .c file it still works but I get the following message:

QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication

I am using QML and “QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);”

The timer still works but I do not understand where the issue is.  All this brings me to the point of having some additional questions. (See next comment)

Comment: So far in my app I am NOT creating or using any additional threads. If I just create the timer object in the main function everything sems to work but if I move it anywhere else, why must I wrap it in a QThread?

Now that you have very generously provided a working HeartBeatTimer class, why can I not move its creation from main.c to another c file without the above warning?

Do you know where I can get additional information/training regarding how all of this is working behind the scenes?

Comment: ```QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication``` ---maybe you created some global variables before the creation of qapplication?        ```information/training```-- qt documentation,qt source code,stackoverflow? i dunno where to get additional info.